# Want to convert given source table into expected Target

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Want to conver below source to expected Target Table.
Source:

```
========================
Course | Year  | Earning
========================
.NET   | 2012  | 10000
Java   | 2012  | 20000
.NET   | 2012  | 5000
.NET   | 2013  | 48000
Java   | 2013  | 30000
```

Expected Output:

```
=====================
Year  | .NET  | Java
=====================
2012  | 15000 | 20000
2013  | 48000 | 30000
```

Comment: Please add some code that you tried and didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like rows to column problem. Here i am assuming you have only .Net and Java courses available. if you have more, you need to add more columns to below transformations.

1. First use expression transformation with below out ports. They will calculate earning for each course.

```
java =  = IIF(Course ='Java', earning, 0)
dotnet=  = IIF(Course ='.Net', earning, 0)
```

2. Use an aggregator to calculate those columns.

```
Year -- input output port with group by
out_java = SUM(java)
out_dotnet = SUM(dotnet)
```

3. Link Year, out_java ,out_dotnet  to corresponding target columns.

So, whole mapping should look like

```
SQ --> EXP--> AGG --> Target
```